# Default sans-serif for T1

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

When using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, my understanding was that the fonts were pretty much the same as the defaults, except that they carried native accentuated characters.  Now, I use sans-serif in my document, and the difference is really important between T1 and the default.  Here is the result (top is default, bottom is T1):

[image: Top is normal, bottom is with T1]

**Question:** How can I have the regular sans-serif fonts with a document using T1?  Note; I only need the accents in the main, serifed text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It *is* a big difference. It depends on the tastes of Jörg Knappen who designed the European Modern fonts and apparently liked less heavy sans serif fonts.

With `\usepackage{lmodern}` you'll get the same weight.

[image]