# Set default sans serif font in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, font-encodings, sans-serif

How can I set the default sans serif font to [the default in this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75946/default-sans-serif-for-t1) in XeLaTeX? I can only get Helvetica with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=5pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{times,multicol,graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
```

and I get an error if I use `\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}` in the preamble.

Comment: Your code is for `pdflatex`. XeLaTeX requires `fontspec` package, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Latin Modern Sans Serif`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}

\begin{document}
\textsf{A simple example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, it works ... how do I set the default font for the entire document to sans serif?

Comment: Put `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Sans}` in the preamble.